# Vue and Vuex Instance Across Tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-cli, vuex4

I'm about one month learning Vue. It might be a silly question, but I'm really confused.

I'm creating a cs livechat app with five state and "component is". Welcome -> identity -> wait for queue -> Chat -> end.

The user progress is stored in Vuex. The state changes by listening to "next" event fired by currently active component.

However, when I created three different browser windows (including incognito), things get weird.
I've opened the first instance till it in waiting state. Then, I do the same for the other two instances. When I checked the first one, it was suddenly in end state and the second one is in chat state. I tried to check it's history and found that the first two vue instance **listen** to next event fired by the other. I thought like this because time interval when the event was fired was wide.

Where am I going wrong? It works fine in one tab.

Additional info:
I've tried in development and production build but the result still the same.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="mx-auto pt-6" style="width: 480px; height: 550px">
    <transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
      <component
        :is="currentProgressComponent"
        @next="nextProgress"
        @home="home"
      ></component>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { sendMessage } from '../services/socket'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    identity: { name: '', email: '' },
    target: { name: '', email: '' },
    role: '',
    progress: {
      list: ["welcome", "identity", "wait", "box", "ended"],
      current: 'welcome'
    },
    chats: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_IDENTITY(state, data) {
      state.identity = data
    },
    SET_ROLE(state, data) {
      state.role = data
    },
    SET_PROGRESS(state, newProgressIndex) {
      state.progress.current = state.progress.list[newProgressIndex]
    }
  },
  actions: {
    ....,
    nextProgress(store) {
      const next = store.state.progress.list.indexOf(store.state.progress.current) + 1
      if (next === store.state.progress.list.length) {
        throw new Error('Invalid next progress state')
      }
      store.commit('SET_PROGRESS', next)
    },
    home(store) {
      store.commit('SET_PROGRESS', 0)
    }
  },
})
```

ChatWait.vue

```
export default {
  components: { LoadingSpinner, ExclamationCircleIcon },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const state = ref("registering");
    const queue = ref(-1);
    const errorMessage = ref("");
    const store = useStore();
    const next = ref(false);
    if (store.state.role === "customer") {
      queueUp();
    } else if (store.state.role === "admin") {
      setAdminAvailability();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Invalid role");
    }
    const queuedCallback = ({ error, message }) => {
      if (error) {
        state.value = "error";
        errorMessage.value = message;
      } else {
        if (store.state.role === "customer") {
          state.value = "queued";
          getQueueNumber();
        } else if (store.state.role === "admin") {
          state.value = "waiting";
        }
      }
    };
    const queueNumberCallback = (number) => {
      queue.value = number;
      if (number < 2 && number >= 0) {
        joinConversation();
      } else if (number > 10) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          getQueueNumber();
        }, 10000);
      } else if (number > 5) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          getQueueNumber();
        }, 5000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          getQueueNumber();
        }, 1000);
      }
    };
    registerWaitingCallbacks(queuedCallback, queueNumberCallback);
    registerChatCallbacks(() => {
      next.value = true;
    }, store);
    watchEffect(() => {
      if (next.value) {
        console.log("I am from chat wait");
        emit("next");
      }
    });
    return {
      state,
      queue,
      errorMessage,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...
  },
};
```

Note: it doesnt log 'I am from chat wait' when the component changed

Comment: I'm pretty sure that for every tab (so a Vuejs app) exists a vuex store, which means that tabs doesn't share the state across multiple tabs. Unless you synchronize the content of the store via localStorage. In the code i saw that you 're using sockets tho (correct me if i'm wrong), are you sure you assigned like an instance ID to every instance of the app so they are not listening to the events they are not supposed to share?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Socket Io. I'm not assigning unique id for the client side. However, I do use socket id for identifier in my backend. Idk if its id would be equal accross different tab